# Saving registers state in COM program

Tags: c, assembly, dos, cpu-registers

I disassembled a simple DOS .COM program and there was some code which saves and restores registers values

```
PUSH AX ; this is the first instruction
PUSH CX
....
POP CX
POP AX
MOV AX, 0x00 0x4C
INT 21 // call DOS interrupt 21 => END
```

This is very similar to function prologue and epilogue in C programs. But prologues are added automatically by compiler, and the program above was written manually in assembler, so the programmer took full responsibility for saving and restoring values in this code.

My question is what will happen if I unintentionally forgot to save some registers in my program?

And what if I intentionally replace these instructions to `NOP` in HEX editor? Will this lead to program crash? And why called function is responsible for saving outer context on the stack? From my point of view this should be done somehow in calling function to prevent problems if I use 3rd party libraries and poorly written code which may break my program execution.

Comment: It's assembler, so there are no strict rules.  If you screw up, something will happen.  In the snippet above, there is no point in preserving AX anyway.

Comment: the saved registers contain the callers' values,  they are saved because the current program is going to modify them.  The restoration of the register values at the end of the program are so the caller can continue without having their register values unexpectedly modified

Comment: I think if we call a DOS COM program as a child process using AX=4B00h int 21h, then the content of all registers will be lost and a caller (parent process) have to be preserve the content into its own space just before calling a child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem of making the calling function save all of its working registers before calling another function is that sometimes a function is interrupted (i.e. a hardware interrupt) without its knowledge. In DOS, for example, there was that pesky 54 millisecond timer tick. 18 times per second, a hardware interrupt would transfer control from whatever code was executing to the timer tick handler. This happened automatically unless your program specifically disabled interrupts.

The timer tick handler would then save all of the registers it was going to use, do its work, and then restore the registers it saved before returning.

Sure, you could say that interrupt handlers are special, but why? Even with the paucity of registers on the 8086 (AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, Flags -- did I forget anything? I purposely didn't include the segment registers), making a function save its entire state before transferring control means that you'd be using a lot of unnecessary stack space and execution cycles to save things because they *might* be modified. But if the called function is responsible for saving just the registers it uses, and it only uses AX and CX, then it can save just those two registers. It makes for smaller and faster code, and much less stack space usage.

When you start talking about call hierarchies that are many levels deep, the difference between pushing 8 registers rather than 2 registers adds up pretty quickly.

Consider the x86-64, with its 64 general purpose registers. Do you really think a function should be forced to save all 64 of those registers before calling another function, even when the called function only uses two of them? Saving 64 64-bit registers requires 512 bytes of stack space. As opposed to saving two registers requiring only 16 bytes.

The primary point of writing things in assembly language these days is to write faster and smaller code than what a compiler can write. A guiding principle is don't do more work than you have to. That means it's up to you to know what registers your assembly language function is using, and to save those registers on entry and restore them on exit.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to guard against forgetting what to `push` or `pop` I would advise sticking to a higher level language.

In assembler, if the function is your own then you should save and restore all registers you use within the function except those which return an output from the function. If others wrote the function, look up its documentation. If in doubt, save/restore registers before/after calling the function (except those which are supposed to return a value).

Answer (score 1):

Since **the DOS Terminate function does not rely on any register settings (other than AX) for its operation** (*) both pushes/pops in the code you have posted *seem* superfluous. You should however be aware that the programmer could have pushed these values for the purpose of using them locally! So replacing both these pushes by `NOP` in HEX editor is surely a bad idea. You could however replace both pops by `NOP` because at that point in the program the restoration of AX/CX as well as balancing the stack are unnecessary because of (*).

Since your question is about saving registers on **the program level** the answer must be that *pushing/popping registers for the sake of saving them* is useless. Nothing bad will happen if you unintentionally forgot to save some registers in your program.

Comment: At least an answer that relates to the original question.